# is it possible for two people, using different emacs and keybindings to edit the same file synchronously?

Tags: server

I want to pair program with a couple of people but my keybindings in emacs are not the same as theirs. Is there a way to edit the same file but keep the keybindings different?

Comment: You can use any key bindings you like in any Emacs session you like. What do you mean by "my keybindings in emacs are completely foreign"?

Comment: It's probably worth reading [Collaborative Editing](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CollaborativeEditing)

Comment: Why not run two copies of emacs?  If the config files are an issue you could use something like https://github.com/plexus/chemacs

Comment: @CroadLangshan how would they update the same buffer?

Comment: `auto-revert-mode`?  Not the same buffer, but the same file, within a few seconds.  Is the person you're pairing with local or remote, by the way?